# how to update table from array multidimension with php

Tags: php, string, foreach

how can i update data from array multidimension in php, but its from key and value array like this :

```
$array1=array(
    array('data1'=>'name','data2'=>'age'),
    array('data1'=>'names','data2'=>'ages')
);
```

how can i get result from array like this

```
UPDATE tablename SET data1='name',data2='age' WHERE 1;
```

i tried this but the result not like above

```
foreach($array1 as $arrays) {
    foreach($arrays as $key => $value){
        echo $key."="."'".$value."'".", ";
    }
}
```

result:

```
data1='name',data2='age', data1='name',data2='age'
```

i want result like this :

```
data1='name',data2='age'
```

i hope can help me.

Comment: You only used first array datas in query

Comment: So you want to use the data from your first array element only, or what …?

Comment: You don't need 2 foreaches. `foreach($array as $data){ var_dump($data); }`

Comment: no, its will looping in upload

Answer (score 0):

Because you only want to get content of first array, you should loop through first array only

```
foreach($array1[0] as $key => $value){
    echo $key."="."'".$value."'".", ";
}
// data1='name', data2='age',
```

Comment: I want to use the second array for upload loping

Comment: @exsanrenaldhi You shown first array in result string

Comment: i cant update if like this UPDATE table SET data1='name', data2='age',data1='names', data2='ages' WHERE 1 ,

Comment: but with loop UPDATE table SET data1='name', data2='age' WHERE 1;

Comment: how i can access   array('data1'=>'names','data2'=>'ages')

Comment: @exsanrenaldhi Use `$array1[1]` instead of `$array1[0]` in `foreach`